# How to supply multiple URIs as type value during attribute exchange inside <openid-atribute> tag in security-context.xml?

Tags: openid, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.0.5 to provide the authentication and authorization in the web site I am working on... for accessing email attribute I have defined  as follows...
`<security:openid-attribute name="email" type="http://schema.openid.net/contact/email" required="true" count="2"/>`

Now I want to provide the support for all the three attribute types [All the three types](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/03/how-to-pretty-much-guarantee-that-you.html). How can I provide support for multiple attributes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some relatively extensive customization, what you describe isn't really possible in Spring Security 3.0.5. You have a couple options that I can think of:

Create different `openid-attribute` mappings for each possible schema combination. For example:

```
<security:openid-attribute name="email" type="http://axschema.org/contact/email" required="true" count="2"/>
<security:openid-attribute name="email2" type="http://schema.openid.net/contact/email" required="true" count="2"/>
<security:openid-attribute name="email3" type="http://openid.net/schema/contact/email" required="true" count="2"/>
```

The pain of this option is that you would need to look at 3 different attribute values when you are trying to do something with these attributes.

Use the Spring Security 3.1 functionality supporting `identifier-matcher` on each `openid-attribute` element to narrow the use of particular schemas by OpenID provider. The benefit of this is that you could potentially use only a single attribute name, and expect the `identifier-matcher` functionality to pick the right one. The downside is that you will need to do the homework of figuring out which OpenID providers support which schemas and attributes.

Unfortunately, not a great solution in either case - welcome to the world of OpenID AX :)

Comment: thanks @Peter.... I have already tried the option1 .. In the order similar as u suggested.. Problem is that code works perfectly fine for google but not for others (yahoo,myopenid,aol,wordpress etc)... any clue ?